# How do I unban user with commands?

Tags: discord.js

I am trying to make a command that unbans someone.

I have tried `member.unban`, `message.guild.unban` and the current one,
`message.guild.members.unban`.

I am not quite sure what to do.

Here is my current code:

```js
    const Discord = require('discord.js');

    module.exports = {
        name: "unban",
        description: "unbans a member from the server",
        
    
        async run (client, message, args) {
    
            if(!message.member.hasPermission("BAN_MEMBERS")) return message.channel.send('You can\'t use that!')
            if(!message.guild.me.hasPermission("BAN_MEMBERS")) return message.channel.send('I don\'t have the permissions.')
    
            const member = message.mentions.members.first();
    
            if(!args[0]) return message.channel.send('Please specify a user');
    
    
    
            
    
            let reason = args.slice(1).join(" ");
    
            if(!reason) reason = 'Unspecified';
    
            message.guild.members.unban(`${member}`, `${reason}`)
            .catch(err => {
                if(err) return message.channel.send('Something went wrong')
            })
    
            const banembed = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
            .setTitle('Member Unbanned')
            .addField('User Unbanned', member)
            .addField('Unbanned by', message.author)
            .addField('Reason', reason)
            .setFooter('Time Unbanned', client.user.displayAvatarURL())
            .setTimestamp()
    
            message.channel.send(banembed);
    
    
        }
    }
```

I don't get any error on my command prompt, but this is what shows up in discord: [Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tEEvR.png) and the user remains unbanned.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to pass a [UserResolvable](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/typedef/UserResolvable) to the `.unban()` method. Putting the `member` object inside a [template string](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/template_strings) (`${member}`) will turn it into a string that mentions the user, and won't work.

The way you're doing it will also probably not work due to users not being mentionable as `GuildMember`s when they're banned from the server.

To go around that, you can change your command so it unbans people by their IDs instead (`!unban 873478935468795467`). Code would then look like this:

```js
message.guild.members.unban(id)
```

(`id` being a string that contains the id)

*I highly recommend that you check [the docs](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/GuildMemberManager?scrollTo=unban) out. They have great examples for these situations.*

Comment: so i tried using `const userid = message.mentions.members.first().id;` to get the id but that isn't working.

Comment: You can't mention a user that isn't in the guild

Comment: i noticed that, so i just started using the id of the person, saying it is an unknown ban, but he user is in fact banned

Comment: Cool! Care to share your working code as an answer for people that get to this thread later?

Answer (score 0):

In discord.Is v13 you can use

```
Let target = args[1];
Let reason = args.slice(2).join(“ “);
If (!reason) reason = ‘N/A’;
Message.guild.bans.fetch().then(bans => {
    Bans.forEach(banned => {
        If (banned.user.username === target) {
            Message.guild.members.unban(banned.user.id, reason);
        }
    });
});
```